# Trying to remove Android SMS and CALL_LOG permissions per Play Console, but can't find them

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

The Play Dev Console warns me that my app will be impacted by a policy change governing the use of SMS and CALL_LOG permissions, however I can't find that those permissions are used in my app. Here are the permissions the app uses, which I verified by opening the APK in Android Studio and reviewing AndroidManifest.xml:

```
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
android.permission.VIBRATE
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT
```

Are any of the above triggers for the SMS or CALL_LOG permission? Relevant information: This is an old app that I'm trying hard not to need to recompile, although it may be unavoidable.

Comment: Maybe you are using a lib that uses those two

Comment: But wouldn't it show up in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I found the answer. In [Google's permissions documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_CALL_LOG), they say that the READ_CONTACTS permission is a trigger for the *_CALL_LOG permissions, and this happens only if your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are <= 15. This describes my situation in this aging app, so my next step will be to either try to minimally tweak it and sign it, or else bite the bullet and modernize the whole build.

Comment: So can we decrease the targetSdkVersion="28" to less than 15 ?  if yes, then can you please suggest?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, to solve the problem I changed the binary of the internal test because I only had changed the production binary.

Comment: Glad you solved it. This didn't apply to my case, but it is a good observation and may help some more people. Google lets you apply for an extension but absent that the deadline is coming right up.

Comment: Did the warning show permanently in Google Play until you removed it?

Comment: We had the same - and to answer @Panther - yes warning only went when old Testing track version was replaced.

Comment: @Dazed The deadline is over so it doesn't matter anymore. My app survived :)